# mv command creates directories

Tags: linux, bash, mv

I am facing a very weird issue.
Consider an example I have these directories "/ten" and "/one/two/three/four" I have a few files in these directories.
When i execute the following command

```
mv /ten/ /one/two/three/four/five/six
```

it gives the output as 
mv: cannot move '/ten/' to '/one/two/three/four/five/six' : No such file or directory. Which looks fine as it doesn't create directories.

But if I execute the following command

```
mv /one/two/three/four/ /one/two/five/six
```

the directories five/six get created inside /one/two. i.e. the mv command succeeds.

Can anyone please explain what is happening here ? Why doesn't it give an error No such file or directory ?

EDIT : Further Observation ..

Directories /one/two/three/four exists also directories /one/two/five exists.
Executing `mv /one/two/three/four/ /one/two/five/six` will succeed. Here directory six will get created even though it is not present.
This doesn't happen in the case when I execute `mv /one/two/three/four /one/two/five/six` and the "five" directory doesn't exists. In this case it will give error.

I thought mv will never create any directories.

Please let me know if I have missed something obvious.

Comment: I don't see that behavior.  `mkdir -p one/two/three; mv one/two/three one/four/five` errors with No such file or directory.

Comment: Are you really sure `five/six` didn't already exist?

Comment: Or did `/one/two/five` exist?

Comment: try `[[ -d /one/two/five ]] && mv /one/two/three/four/ /one/two/five/six`

Comment: By the way, why do you perform these experiments as `root`? Or otherwise how did you create `/one/` directory?

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov : The above directories are just an example. Though I am using the root user as I am writing a script which is kind of  Installer

Comment: @WilliamPursell and Others : Yes I missed to say that /one/two/five existed... Sorry about that .. Please see my edits ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you're executing another `mv` binary, executing another version of `mv`, or something is wrapping it up like a function, a script or perhaps an alias.

To know if you're really running the real `mv` or not, run

```
type mv
```

You should get

```
mv is /bin/mv
```

As suggested by [Etan Reisner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981051/mv-command-creates-directories/24981099?noredirect=1#comment38834499_24981099), you can also add `-a` to have more information:

```
type -a mv
```

#### UPDATE

> Directories /one/two/three/four exists also directories /one/two/five
>   exists. Executing mv /one/two/three/four/ /one/two/five/six will
>   succeed. Here directory six will get created even though it is not
>   present. This doesn't happen in the case when I execute mv
>   /one/two/three/four /one/two/five/six and the "five" directory doesn't
>   exists. In this case it will give error.

Since `/one/two/five` existed it simply moved your directory `/one/two/three/four` as `/one/two/five/six`. That means `/one/two/five/six` is now the new name or pathname of the directory which was previously `/one/two/three/four`.

Comment: Output from `type mv` of `mv is aliased to \`mv -i'` would be normal also (though less helpful in this case). `type -a mv` might be better.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes it could be better thanks. Updated.

Comment: Even if he has an alias, why would it work differently in the two cases?

Comment: @Barmar I didn't really examine that. Probably it doesn't really make a difference unless the alias points to another wrapper.

Comment: I get the same output mv is /bin/mv .. Please see my Question .. I have made some edits.

Comment: Thanks for providing better understanding..

Answer (score 1):

The problem in understanding you are having can be helped with a reference to the `man page` for `mv` and a few examples. From `man 1 mv` **Rename SOURCE to DEST, or move SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.** What is not apparent is what is `SOURCE` and what is `DEST` and this is where your confusion arises. For example:

```
mv /ten/ /one/two/three/four/five/six
it gives the output as mv: cannot move '/ten/' to '/one/two/three/four/five/six' : 
No such file or directory. Which looks fine as it doesn't create directories.
```

It doesn't. In you example, the `SOURCE` is `/ten` and, your `DEST` depends on whether `/one/two/three/four/five` exists and also whether `/one/two/three/four/five/six` exists.

If `/one/two/three/four/five` exists, then `mv /ten /one/two/three/four/five` will cause `/ten` to be moved and become a new subdirectory of `/one/two/three/four/five`. e.g. `/one/two/three/four/five/ten`.

If `/one/two/three/four/five` exists (but not ../six), then `mv /ten /one/two/three/four/five/six` will cause `/ten` to be moved and become `six` new subdirectory of `/one/two/three/four/five`. e.g. `/one/two/three/four/five/six`.

if however `/one/two/three/four/five` do not exist, then `mv` will fail because you have not provided a valid `DEST`.

Comment: Thanks for providing better understanding..

Comment: Sure, glad I could help. I remember having the same misunderstanding years ago...